# Understanding recursive function with implicit return statement

Tags: scala

Below recursive method sums the integer values between a range

```
  def sumInts(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    if(a > b) 0
    else {
      println(a +"," + b)
      a + sumInts(a + 1 , b)
    }
   }
```

So `sumInts(2 , 5) returns 14`

I'm confused about how the recursive call to sumInts sums the integer range. Can explain textually how this method works ?

How does sumInts return the incremented value ?? Perhaps I am missing something fundamental to recursion here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It calculates the sum of values in the range [a, b] by first calculating the sum of the range [a+1, b] (by recursively calling `sumInts(a + 1 , b)`) then adding `a` to it.

**[Update]** In Scala, the `return` statement is optional; functions return the value of the last expression evaluated. Thus the above function body is equivalent to

```
if(a > b) return 0
else {
  println(a +"," + b)
  return a + sumInts(a + 1 , b)
}
```

**[/Update]**

Which for the range [2, 5] it would do the following (I removed the `println` call for the sake of simplicity, and added brackets to mark recursive calls):

1. `if(2 > 5) 0 else 2 + sumInts(2 + 1, 5)` which, the condition being `false`, evaluates to
2. `2 + sumInts(3, 5)`
3. `2 + (if(3 > 5) 0 else 3 + sumInts(3 + 1, 5))` which evaluates to
4. `2 + (3 + sumInts(4, 5))`
5. `2 + (3 + (if(4 > 5) 0 else 4 + sumInts(4 + 1, 5)))` which evaluates to
6. `2 + (3 + (4 + sumInts(5, 5)))`
7. `2 + (3 + (4 + (if(5 > 5) 0 else 5 + sumInts(5 + 1, 5))))` which evaluates to
8. `2 + (3 + (4 + (5 + sumInts(6, 5))))`
9. `2 + (3 + (4 + (5 + (if(6 > 5) 0 else 6 + sumInts(6 + 1, 5)))))` which, the condition being `true`, evaluates to
10. `2 + (3 + (4 + (5 + (0))))`

Comment: thanks, the point I was missing also is that the 'a' variable is incremented on each subsequent call.

Comment: be careful with this affirmation, the `a` is never actually "updated", it's more correct to say that for each recursive call, the method gets called with a different parameter value, but `a` stays the same during each recursion.